# Distinct on multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I Have a List of some Properties as Model

```
public class AnswerList {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? Schedule_ID { get; set; }
    public int? SubItemID { get; set; }
    public string SubItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string Remarks_Flag { get; set; }
    public string Lattitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Load_Date { get; set; }
}
```

I was getting list of Distinct Sub Items from this List

```
List<string> sub_item_list = AnswerList.Select(x => x.SubItemName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now I want data in different format as per below class

```
public class SubItemList {
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string SubItemName { get; set; }
}
```

My requirement is to get distinct sub item with their respective Item Names , Sub Item should be distinct but Item Name can be repeated as one Item can contain multiple Subitem

Distinct Does not work on multiple values so I tried

```
List<SubItemList> SI_List = 
                 AnswerList.GroupBy(d => d.SubItemID)
                           .Select(x => 
                               new SubItemList 
                         { 
                          ItemName = x.Select(a => a.ItemName).First(), 
                          SubItemName = x.Select(a => a.SubItemName).First() 
                         }).Distinct().ToList();
```

This way I am getting what I want but I don't think its a preferable approach ,
Linq expression inside another Linq expression

How can I get it with a simple Linq expression ?

I am using ASP.Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
GroupBy(
        p => new {p.ItemName, p.SubItemName}
       ).Select(g => new { g.Key.ItemName, g.Key.SubItemName });
```

Comment: Works with Little  Modification GroupBy(p => new { p.ItemName, p.SubItemName }).Select(g => new SubItemList{ItemName= g.Key.ItemName, SubItemName= g.Key.SubItemName }).ToList();

Comment: Query in the accepted answer and one you have asked in the question are not same. In question post `GroupBy` you are only considering the first record of the projected collection and ignoring the rest. Until and unless `GroupBy SubItemID` means same value for `ItemName` and the `SubItemName`

Comment: As I got it the issue, SubItemId will map to SubItemName. ItemName can be repeated, and can contains SubItemName. Just Jack don’t know how to get group with multiple fields here.

Answer (score 2):

If the expectation is what you have asked in the question, then following shall be the query:

```
AnswerList.GroupBy(d => new { d.SubItemID, d.ItemName, d.SubItemName})
                         .Select(x => new SubItemList{
                                     ItemName = x.Key.ItemName, 
                                     SubItemName =x.Key.SubItemName
                            }
                  ).Distinct();
```

> How it works

1. GroupBy unique combination of `SubItemID`, `ItemName`, `SubItemName`, which will form the grouping key
2. Now only Pick the `ItemName`, `SubItemName` to create `SubItemList` and call Distinct to remove duplicates even across `SubItemID`

For `Distinct` to work correctly for the class `SubItemList` either implement `IEquatable<SubItemList>` or supply the `IEqualityComparer<SubItemList>` to the Distinct